# Continuous function with certain characteristics

Tags: real-analysis, integration, continuity

I've been tasked with the following question:

> Provide an example of a one-variable function that has the following characteristics:
>
> 1. The function is continuous at $0$
> 2. Its integral from $0$ to $\infty$ is convergent but the function does not tend to zero as $x\rightarrow\infty$

Comment: What have you tried? People here get cranky (and downvote) if they don't see any work (they're suspicious that it's just people being lazy on their homeworks).

Comment: So $f(x)$ is continuous, but $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)\ne0$. So there must be some $\epsilon_0>0$ such that for any $k>0$ we can find $x_k>k$ with $|f(x_k)|>\epsilon_0$. Yet the $\int_0^\infty f(x)\ dx$ exists (and is less than $\infty$). So what thoughts have you had about how to achieve such characteristics? Note that there is nothing in the statement requiring $f(x)$ to be monotone decreasing. It can be zero except for short (continuous) blips upward.

Answer (score 1):

How about $\sin(x^2)$. This doesn't converge, but the integral does, as can be seen by substituting $u=x^2$.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like:
$$
  f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{2^n}{\sqrt{\pi}} \exp\left(-2^{4n}(x-n)^2\right)\right)
$$

This function is analytic, it satisfies $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)\neq 0$ because in fact the limit does not exist, and because
$$
  \int_{-\infty}^\infty \left(\frac{2^n}{\sqrt{\pi}} \exp\left(-2^{4n}(x-n)^2\right)\right)dx=2^{-n}
$$

... it also satisfies $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\,dx = 2$.

($f$ is just a sum of [Gaussian functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_function), a.k.a. the pdf of the normal distribution, copied at each integer $n = 1, 2, 3, \ldots$ so that at each successive integer, the next peak is twice as high, but four times as narrow.)